# GADTs for Representing Function Application with Multiple Parameters (AST)

Tags: ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree, gadt

I saw in the OCaml manual this example to use GADT for an AST with function application:

```
type _ term =
  | Int : int -> int term
  | Add : (int -> int -> int) term
  | App : ('b -> 'a) term * 'b term -> 'a term

let rec eval : type a. a term -> a = function
  | Int n    -> n
  | Add      -> (fun x y -> x+y)
  | App(f,x) -> (eval f) (eval x)
```

Is this the right way of representing function application for a language **not** supporting partial application?

Is there a way to make a GADT supporting function application with an arbitrary number of arguments?

Finally, is GADT a good way to represent a typed AST? Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, partial eval already works here:

```
# eval (App(App(Add, Int 3),Int 4)) ;;
- : int = 7   

# eval (App(Add, Int 3)) ;;
- : int -> int = <fun>   

# eval (App(Add, Int 3)) 4 ;;
- : int = 7
```

What you don't have in this small gadt is abstraction (lambdas), but it's definitely possible to add it.

If you are interested in the topic, there is an abundant (academic) literature. [This](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~puech/typeful.pdf) paper presents various encoding that supports partial evaluation.

There are also non-Gadt solutions, as shown in [this paper](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/APLAS.pdf).

In general, GADT are a very interesting way to represent *evaluators*. They tend to fall a bit short when you try to transform the AST for compilations (but there are [ways](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/papers/MCGN15.html)).

Also, you have to keep in mind that you are encoding the type system of the language you are defining in your host language, which means that you need an encoding of the type feature you want. Sometimes, it's tricky.

Edit: A way to have a GADT *not* supporting partial eval is to have a special value type not containing functions and a "functional value" type with functions. Taking the simplest representation of the first paper, we can modify it that way:

```
type _ v =
  | Int : int -> int v
  | String : string -> string v

and _ vf =
  | Base : 'a v -> ('a v) vf
  | Fun : ('a vf -> 'b vf) -> ('a -> 'b) vf

and _ t =
  | Val : 'a vf -> 'a t
  | Lam : ('a vf -> 'b t) -> ('a -> 'b) t
  | App : ('a -> 'b) t * 'a t -> 'b t

let get_val : type a . a v -> a = function
  | Int i -> i
  | String s -> s

let rec reduce : type a . a t -> a vf = function
  | Val x -> x
  | Lam f -> Fun (fun x -> reduce (f x))
  | App (f, x) -> let Fun f = reduce f in f (reduce x)

let eval t =
  let Base v = reduce t in get_val v

(* Perfectly defined expressions. *)
let f = Lam (fun x -> Lam (fun y -> Val x))
let t = App (f, Val (Base (Int 3)))
(* We can reduce t to a functional value. *)
let x = reduce t
(* But we can't eval it, it's a type error. *)
let y = eval t

(* HOF are authorized. *)
let app = Lam (fun f -> Lam (fun y -> App(Val f, Val y)))
```

You can make that arbitrarly more complicated, following your needs, the important property is that the `'a v` type can't produce functions.

Comment: I know partial application is supported with this GADT, but I want to do a GADT **not** supporting it (for a C-like language) while still supporting multiple arguments. I could use the current GADT to do this (using partial application), but the problem I see with this approach is that I can create an AST that is invalid. As I want to do compilation, I'll look at the other solutions, but it is still interesting to see what is a solution to the problem in my question.

Comment: Do you want to forbid high order functions too ?

Comment: No, but I don't know how to make a GADT to represent this.

Comment: Edited the post with an answer. :)

Comment: I also did [this](https://bpaste.net/show/8d258b7dde39) which may be closer to what you want too. It's a trade off question. This one forbids partial application *inside the language* (where the previous one forbids to evaluate to a function).